# bitbucket - can not see commit of merged branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

My Company hosted code on bitbucket - Git.  The way we work is create branch for every issue, individual person work on that branch. Once work done he raise Pull Request. Before raising PR, he rebase code with master branch. Other people in team review his PR & then approve it. Once PR approve, same individual merge it to master branch

I created branch on 2nd June & PR was merge on 14th June.  Branch had 3 commits in 3 different files. Subsequently other developer's branch was merge on 26th June. He also work on 2 files, which I change.  Now after more than month, when I check file history, I dont see my commit there.    Out of 3 files I change, only 1 file changes are there & they show correct commit number. And other 2 commits not showing in file history. I can guess, my changes been overridden, but git history for file, must show the commit.

Is anybody have idea, how it can be happen. I mean how commit been vanished for particular file in git history.

Thanks
Aniruddha

Comment: does any force push happened in between?

Comment: @MaNKuR : Probably Yes. I dont have definite answer because We work in 3 different locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our company uses a similar process:

1. We work in issue branches
2. Create a Pull Request in BitBucket
3. Senior Devs review and approve (or not)
4. If no merge conflicts are present they merge
5. If there are merge conflicts the dev has to resolve them they will merge it

Note I say merge here, not rebase.  Rebasing is fraught with peril for the unwary. When you rebase, you are abandoning existing commits and creating new ones that are similar but different. If you push to BitBucket and others pull them down and base work on them, and then you rewrite those commits with `git rebase` and push them up again, your coworkers will have to re-merge their work and things will get messy when you try to pull their work back into yours. Likely something along these lines occurred where a coworker rebased his work while your branch was out (or theirs) and crushed your commit. It's possible to unwind this lot with judicious use of `git log` to figure out which commit is which.

Going forward, I recommend merging over rebasing. As I mention above, if there are no merge conflicts on a Pull Request, do nothing.  If there are, here is the process to resolve them:

```
git fetch origin <Team's Main Branch>
git merge FETCH_HEAD <your branch>
-- make and stage fixes
git commit
git push
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion rebase vs merge. Is it possible to explain what exactly happen & how can I verify that?